# fileChooser.setDialogType() Doesn't Work

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have code that is supposed to choose a folder from a `JFileChooser`, but it still is acting like its choosing a file, even if I use `fs.setDialogType`. I tried `showSaveDialog` and `showOpenDialog`, but they both don't work.
Here is my code:

```
public static String getFolder() {
    JFileChooser fs = new JFileChooser();
    fs.setDialogType(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    fs.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (fs.getSelectedFile() != null)
        return fs.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    return "null";
}
```

Comment: You know that there is a documentation for each commen Java class, right? It is called [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setDialogType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setDialogType-int-) is used to set the open, save or custom type for the dialog. Use `setFileSelectionMode` to specify the whether the dialog should select files or directories

```
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```